# How to combine Select, where and label functions in google sheets query

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to query a column and select cells that contain the word: pink. I want to give this new column a new name: Biz priority.
Current formulas I've tried but getting errors for all of them:

1. `=QUERY(N:N,"SELECT N WHERE N CONTAINS 'pink', LABEL * 'Biz Priority'"),1`
2. `=QUERY(N:N,"SELECT N LABEL N 'Biz Priority', WHERE N CONTAINS 'pink'"),1`
3. `=QUERY(N:N,"SELECT N LABEL * 'Biz Priority', WHERE N CONTAINS 'pink'"),1`

This works: `=QUERY(N:N,"SELECT N WHERE N CONTAINS 'pink'"),1` but the column title is the same as another column which won't work for me. TIA

Comment: Resolved: ```=QUERY(N:N,"SELECT N WHERE N CONTAINS 'pink' LABEL N 'Biz Priority'",1)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On:

`=QUERY(N:N,"SELECT N WHERE N CONTAINS 'pink', LABEL * 'Biz Priority'"),1`

Remove the comma before `LABEL`, change `*` to `N`, move the `)` to the end.

`=QUERY(N:N,"SELECT N WHERE N CONTAINS 'pink' LABEL N 'Biz Priority' ",1)`

You can also make it case-insensistive:

`=QUERY(N:N,"SELECT N WHERE LOWER(N) CONTAINS 'pink' LABEL N 'Biz Priority' ",1)`